# passing commands to cmd through visual studio in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to pass a command to cmd and read the output given by cmd in visual studio, in a textbox. How will I do it?

Comment: Is opening a console really that hard?

Comment: is this you looking for- DevEnv.exe /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean in your application you're within *within visualstudio*:

```
// Use Process to start (and execute) the `cmd`:
var cmd = new Process
{
    StartInfo = newProcessStartInfo
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,

        Filename = "cmd.com",
        //Arguments = "foo bar baz" // if necessary
    }
};

// run it
cmd.Start();

// then get the returned output and place it in your textbox
while (!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    String content = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // textbox1.Text += content;
}
```

Otherwise, if you're looking to just copy CMD output at development time, just run the command, then use the application menu to select and copy the text.

Comment: @downvoter: In my defense, the OP is very ambiguous...